# What is an infinite-partite graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

The abstract of the paper [Density conditions for triangles in multipartite graphs](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/stephan.thomasse/liste/triangle.pdf) has the following sentence:

> Also we show that an **infinite-partite graph** with finite parts has a triangle, provided that the edge density between any two parts is greater than 1/2.

The paper does not define the term "infinite-partite graph". I also googled this term and could not find any definitions. **What does infinte-partite mean?**

It seems like any graph could be infinite-partite—just put each vertex in its own part? This is not a very interesting concept though so "infinite-partite" must mean something else. But then where do the "finite parts" come in?

Comment: The paper has an answer to this.

Comment: I looked through the paper and could not find a definition. Where are you finding this answer? @zhoraster

Comment: There is no definition of infinite-partite graph, I didn't say that. But the meaning of that sentence from the abstract becomes clear. Just read Section 2.

Comment: I looked at Section 2 already. It does not become clear. It says "Define t n:=d_n(K3), where K3 is the triangle. By Theorem 1, the limit of t_n, as n tends to infinity, is 1/2. However, this result does not imply the existence of t_ω, where t_ω is the smallest real number such that every infinite-partite graph with finite parts and all edge densities strictly greater than t_ω has a triangle. One needs an additional argument.". This assumes knowledge of the term infinite-partite graph.

Comment: I searched through all occurrences of the word "infinite" in this paper and found no definition. I also searched online for "infinite-partite graph" and got nowhere.

Comment: Does proof of Theorem 2 answer that?

Comment: Just putting each vertex in its own pawr is fine until you come to the edge-density condition. If each vertex is its own part, the edge-density condition says you have a complete graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, any infinite graph can be made into an infinite-partite graph by making each vertex a single part.  In the context of this paper, though, when they talk about an $n$-partite graph, they mean a graph $G$ *together with* a specific choice of a partition of its vertices into $n$ independent sets, rather than just a graph for which such a partition exists.  Similarly, then, when they refer to an infinite-partite graph, they mean a specific partition of the vertices into infinitely many independent sets has been chosen.  In particular, an "infinite-partite graph with finite parts" means that each of the chosen independent sets is finite.

Comment: Ah, "finite parts" rather than "finitely many parts". That makes sense, thank you.